# bcache fails to attach local ssd as caching device in google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, ssd

I'm trying to setup bcache in an instance in google cloud using a raid of local SSDs as caching device but everything fails in the attach phase of the process. For testing purposes I created a new instance with blank disks (two SSDs and four Local SSDs). The objective is to have one regular SSD as backing device and form a raid with the 4 Local SSDs and use that device as caching.

In the output below you can see the steps taken (the outcome is the same when using a raid, I just used one Local SSD for simplicity here and because I believe the issue is not related to raid but to the disks themselves). When using the Local SSD as caching device, I fail to attach the caching device to the backing device. When instead I use a regular SSD for caching device, you can see that everything works as expected.

**The question for you experts out there is: Are there any known limitations for the Local SSDs or am I doing anything wrong (or maybe there are some extra steps needed)?**

For reference, these are devices being used:

`/dev/sdb => Backing Device`

`/dev/sdc => SSD Caching Device`

`/dev/nvme0n1 => Local SSD Single Caching Device`

```
# apt update && apt install mdadm bcache-tools -y

# make-bcache -B /dev/sdb
UUID:           cb10650f-cf60-4a96-81eb-7149ae650f94
Set UUID:       dc0a7f3a-de46-4b00-84f4-4aa40c203745
version:        1
block_size:     1
data_offset:        16

# mkfs.ext4 -L cached /dev/bcache0

# make-bcache -C /dev/nvme0n1
UUID:           c5a33c1e-e1ef-4d3d-a5ac-5d0adc340f43
Set UUID:       228dcba5-6085-47a1-b2e9-eff68dd6ac14
version:        0
nbuckets:       768000
block_size:     8
bucket_size:        1024
nr_in_set:      1
nr_this_dev:        0
first_bucket:       1

# bcache-super-show /dev/nvme0n1
sb.magic        ok
sb.first_sector     8 [match]
sb.csum         674DD52F06C4562B [match]
sb.version      3 [cache device]

dev.label       (empty)
dev.uuid        c5a33c1e-e1ef-4d3d-a5ac-5d0adc340f43
dev.sectors_per_block   8
dev.sectors_per_bucket  1024
dev.cache.first_sector  1024
dev.cache.cache_sectors 786430976
dev.cache.total_sectors 786432000
dev.cache.ordered   yes
dev.cache.discard   no
dev.cache.pos       0
dev.cache.replacement   0 [lru]

cset.uuid       228dcba5-6085-47a1-b2e9-eff68dd6ac14

# echo 228dcba5-6085-47a1-b2e9-eff68dd6ac14 > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

# make-bcache -C /dev/sdc
UUID:           55c95063-9aa7-4d2c-8c8c-d4d34d35a7ad
Set UUID:       2de3ccef-a7eb-4620-8b6d-265d0a06da17
version:        0
nbuckets:       204800
block_size:     1
bucket_size:        1024
nr_in_set:      1
nr_this_dev:        0
first_bucket:       1

# bcache-super-show /dev/sdc
sb.magic        ok
sb.first_sector     8 [match]
sb.csum         11E99ECE7A83EABE [match]
sb.version      3 [cache device]

dev.label       (empty)
dev.uuid        55c95063-9aa7-4d2c-8c8c-d4d34d35a7ad
dev.sectors_per_block   1
dev.sectors_per_bucket  1024
dev.cache.first_sector  1024
dev.cache.cache_sectors 209714176
dev.cache.total_sectors 209715200
dev.cache.ordered   yes
dev.cache.discard   no
dev.cache.pos       0
dev.cache.replacement   0 [lru]

cset.uuid       2de3ccef-a7eb-4620-8b6d-265d0a06da17

# echo 2de3ccef-a7eb-4620-8b6d-265d0a06da17 > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach

# bcache-super-show /dev/sdc
sb.magic        ok
sb.first_sector     8 [match]
sb.csum         11E99ECE7A83EABE [match]
sb.version      3 [cache device]

dev.label       (empty)
dev.uuid        55c95063-9aa7-4d2c-8c8c-d4d34d35a7ad
dev.sectors_per_block   1
dev.sectors_per_bucket  1024
dev.cache.first_sector  1024
dev.cache.cache_sectors 209714176
dev.cache.total_sectors 209715200
dev.cache.ordered   yes
dev.cache.discard   no
dev.cache.pos       0
dev.cache.replacement   0 [lru]

cset.uuid       2de3ccef-a7eb-4620-8b6d-265d0a06da17

# bcache-super-show /dev/sdb
sb.magic        ok
sb.first_sector     8 [match]
sb.csum         2E55F82F4131C19B [match]
sb.version      1 [backing device]

dev.label       (empty)
dev.uuid        cb10650f-cf60-4a96-81eb-7149ae650f94
dev.sectors_per_block   1
dev.sectors_per_bucket  1024
dev.data.first_sector   16
dev.data.cache_mode 0 [writethrough]
dev.data.cache_state    1 [clean]

cset.uuid       2de3ccef-a7eb-4620-8b6d-265d0a06da17
```

Answer (score 1):

After some detailed reviewing I realized the problem is with the block size from the different devices. When adjusted the make-bcache commands, everything worked as expected:

```
make-bcache --block 4k -B /dev/sdb
make-bcache --block 4k -C /dev/nvme0n1
```